# Create a multicolumn array in PHP from string

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a multicolumn array from a string where the spearator for the first level array is ";" and for the second level array is ","

This string is given:

```
$string = ("de,text1,text2,text3;en,text1,text2,text3;pl,text1,text2,text3")
```

This is the structure of the array that i want as result:

```
Array
(
    array([de] => text1, text2, text3),
    array([en] => text1, text2, text3),
    array([pl] => text1, text2, text3),
)
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What are you specific issues with your code? Please understand that we are here to _help_, we are _not_ a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_map`, `substr`, `strpos` and `explode` functions:

```
$string = ("de,text1,text2,text3;en,text1,text2,text3;pl,text1,text2,text3");

$items = array_map(function($v){
    $sep_pos = strpos($v, ",");  // position of key/values separator
    return [substr($v, 0, $sep_pos) => substr($v, $sep_pos + 1)];
}, explode(";", $string));

print_r($items);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [de] => text1,text2,text3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [en] => text1,text2,text3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pl] => text1,text2,text3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` and pass array by using `explode`, and inside callback you can explode again with `,` and store it in a variable.

there after you can grab the value using `array_shift`, which needed to be used as a key, and return a new array.

```
$string = "de,text1,text2,text3;en,text1,text2,text3;pl,text1,text2,text3";
$result = array_map(function($value) {
    $temp = explode(',', $value);
    return [array_shift($temp) => implode(',', $temp)];
}, explode(';', $string));
print_r($result);
```

Example: https://eval.in/581893

Comment: plus 1 for fixed solution )

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = "de,text1,text2,text3;en,text1,text2,text3;pl,text1,text2,text3";
$mainArr = explode(";",$string);
$finalArr = array();
foreach($mainArr as $arr) {
   $tempArr = explode(",",$arr);
   reset($tempArr);
   $mainK = $tempArr[0];
   unset($tempArr[key($tempArr)]);
   $finalArr[][$mainK] = implode(",", $tempArr);
}

print '<pre>';print_r($finalArr);print '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [de] => text1,text2,text3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [en] => text1,text2,text3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pl] => text1,text2,text3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$string = "de,text1,text2,text3;en,text1,text2,text3;pl,text1,text2,text3";
$array1 = explode(';', $string);
foreach($array1 as $value){
$temp=explode(',', $value);
$key=$temp[0];
unset($temp[0]);
$new_array[][$key]=$temp;
}
```